# Select data about all participants of a game where a particular user is a participant, including data about the game itself

Tags: sql

I have two tables.

```
GAME_HISTORY
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  game_id                           |  game_activity  |  game_level  |  game_datetime       |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  02741b0009c596be71a2fbeda099af97  |  spelling       |  1           |  2017-12-16 00:00:00 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and

```
GAME_PARTICIPANTS
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  record_id  |  game_id                           |  user_id  |  user_score  |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  83764      |  02741b0009c596be71a2fbeda099af97  |  847642   |  22          |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  83765      |  02741b0009c596be71a2fbeda099af97  |  847643   |  34          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'm trying to write an SQL query – with great difficulty – that fetches:

- Data about all participants of a game where a particular user is a participant (from GAME_PARTICIPANTS)
- Including data about the game itself (from GAME_HISTORY)

Any help would be gratefully received! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint: Use `JOIN`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @zarruq

Comment: Kindly share desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `game_id` using a sub query like below:

```
SELECT G.*, GP.user_id, GP.User_Score
  FROM GAME_PARTICIPANTS GP
  JOIN GAME_HISTORY G
    ON GP.Game_ID = G.Game_ID
 WHERE GP.Game_ID IN (
   SELECT Game_ID FROM GAME_PARTICIPANTS
   WHERE user_id = 847642)
```

See this [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44e6e6/1).

Comment: Yes Joel you may do that way. I thought that while creating the query. :)

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you need to make a join between two table with joining key as `game_id` in the join query itself add one more condition in where clause as `where game_id in(select distinct game_id from game_participant where user_id='847642')`